# Redefining application data folder in uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writing a UWP application to interacting with SQLite database. I implemented a data scheme, that using to create new file in specific directory.

All I found about paths is on the code below. It creates files in %username%\AppData\Local...\Appname_t07g111c25az6\folder_defined_in_code. But I wanna create it in application root folder (C:/Projects/AppName/src/Assets).

Settings.cs

```
static public readonly string DatabasePath = "Database";
static public readonly string DatabaseName = $"{DB_NAME}.db";
static public readonly string DatabasePattern = $"{DB_NAME}.pattern.db";
static public readonly string DatabaseFileName = Path.Combine(DatabasePath, DatabaseName);
static public readonly string DatabasePatternFileName = Path.Combine(DatabasePath, DatabasePattern);
static public readonly string DatabaseUrl = $"{DB_BASEURI}/{DatabaseName}";
public readonly string SQLiteConnectionString = $"Data Source={DatabaseFileName}";
```

Startup.cs

```
private static async Task EnsureSQLiteDatabaseAsync()
        {
            var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; ;
            var databaseFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(AppSettings.DatabasePath, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            if (await databaseFolder.TryGetItemAsync(AppSettings.DatabaseName) == null)
            {
                var sourceFile = await databaseFolder.GetFileAsync(AppSettings.DatabasePattern);
                var targetFile = await databaseFolder.CreateFileAsync(AppSettings.DatabaseName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await sourceFile.CopyAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a read-write SQLite database in the install folder. SQLite databases work only in ApplicationData.

The UWP package (your "application root folder") is read-only once it's been installed, so you can't create or modify a database that is stored there, and you can't write a new one there. The ApplicationData folder (where you are currently creating it) is designed for application specific read-write data, and is the recommended location.

Furthermore, ApplicationData is the only read-write location that the default SQLite implementation can use without modification. You can grant the app access elsewhere (e.g. with the broadFileSystemAccess capability), but SQLite doesn't by default use the right API to make use of that access.

It looks like you're following a standard pattern of including a read-only template of your database in the app package and then copying it to ApplicationData the first time it is needed.